# "Земля Ханаанская" — почему "Ханаанская" с большой буквы?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, прописная-строчная

В Библии названия народностей пишутся с большой буквы. Может поэтому и название земли, где живет народ такой-то, пишется с большой буквы? Каким правилом руководствоваться?

*Мы пришли из земли Ханаанской; Завещал похоронить себя в земле Ханаанской.*
Здесь тоже будет с большой буквы писаться?

P.S. Предложения взяты из детской Библии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В словаре В.В. Лопатина "Как правильно? С большой буквы или с маленькой?" с прописной как древнее название Палестины. Здесь, полагаю, именно это и имеется в виду — завещал похоронить в Палестине, пришли из Палестины.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Может ли контекст влиять на написание прописной/строчной буквы в сочетании "земля Ханаанская"? По отношению к нам, к Лопатину, Ханаанская земля — древнее название Палестины, а по отношению к происходящим событиям, описываемым в Библии, и человеку, который просит похоронить его в ханаанской земле, ханаанская земля — земля его народа. Т.е. тогда не было еще названия Палестины. В Интернете встречаются еще такие сочетания: ханаанский культ, ханаанское побережье, где написание "ханаанский" со строчной, видимо, потому что  значение здесь "принадлежность к определенному народу".

Comment: Контекст, конечно же, исключать нельзя. Но Вы работаете с библией, думаю, что здесь идёт речь именно о неком государственном образовании, если можно так выразиться, этих народов, а не просто о месте обитания. И земля Ханаанская выступает как название этих земель.